# sp_rename error "could be found"?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run the following:

```
EXEC sp_rename '"database_name"."table_name"."old_column_name"', 'new_column_name';
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Msg 15225, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 374
No item by the name of '"database_name"."table_name"."old_column_name"' could be found in the current database 'master', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.
```

Comment: Have a close look at the first word in the error message

Comment: Execute sp_rename in the appropriate database (not 'master')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't properly find the column you're trying to change.

```
USE database_name
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'table_name.old_column_name','new_column_name','COLUMN'
GO
```

It works without the `COLUMN` object type, but added for security purposes.

Look at [Microsoft's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) for more info.